# how to delete for an empty row in a column in python csv

Tags: python, data-cleaning, rowdeleting

I will like to delete all empty row in a column

prices_dataframe[prices_dataframe['postcode'].isnull()]

This only seems to be showing me the empty rows not deleting it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is Null only returns the empty rows it does not drop them. Your empty rows should contain NaN so you can use `prices_dataframe.dropna(inplace=True)
To drop them.

If your rows don't contain NaN you can first replace the empty rows with NaN
`prices_dataframe.replace('', np.nan, inplace=True)` and then drop them

Answer (score 0):

You can use `pandas.DataFrame.dropna` or `pandas.Series.dropna` for this purpose.

Example for a particular column:

```
df = df.dropna("postcode")
```

Example for all columns:

```
df = df.dropna()
```